# Auto Serialisation using Qt Meta Property System

Tags: json, qt, serialization

When I have my custom type with standard Qt types properties, I can do something like this:

```
for (int i = metaObject()->propertyOffset(); i < metaObject()->propertyCount(); i++) {
    auto key = metaObject()->property(i).name();
    setProperty(key, other.property(key));
}
```

I can also create my own type with constructors accepting *QJsonObject*, *QVariant* and any other types, not explicit [e.g. you can type `QJsonObject json = MyType();`]

I've implemented *QVariant* constructor because `other.property(key)` returns *QVariant*. I hoped it will work.

I also can create operators in this type, like

```
virtual operator const QVariant() const {...}
```

or

```
virtual operator const QJsonObject() const {...}
```

But if I have my custom class with `Q_PROPERTY(MyType....)` I cannot just use the loop from the beginning of this post.

So, the question is: how can I implement universal Qt serialization system using just constructors, assign operators and Qt property system (also `Q_DECLARE` and `qRegister`)?

My attemps could be found here:

https://gitlab.com/luntik2012/goodies/blob/master/rfproperty.h

sample seralized class:

```
class Test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name NOTIFY nameChanged)

public:
    Test() = default;
    Test(const QJsonObject &json)
        : QObject()
    {
        // just imagine it will work dynamically. I have my own macro performing this
        for(int i = staticMetaObject.propertyOffset(); i < metaObject()->propertyCount(); i++)
        {
            auto key = metaObject()->property(i).name();
            setProperty(key, json[key]);
        }
    }

    // The same thing as in Json constructor, just shotrened the snippet
    Test(const Test &other) : QObject() { Q_UNUSED(other); }

public:
    Test& operator =(const Test &other) {
        for(int i = staticMetaObject.propertyOffset(); i < metaObject()->propertyCount(); i++)
        {
            auto key = metaObject()->property(i).name();
            setProperty(key, json[key]);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Test& operator =(const QVariant &variant) {
        *this = variant.value<Test>();
        return *this;
    }

signals:
    void nameChanged();

public:
    Q_INVOKABLE QString name() const { return m_name; }

    virtual operator const QJsonObject() const {
        return QJsonObject { { "name", m_name } };
    }

    virtual operator const QVariant() const {
        return QVariant(Test::operator const QJsonObject());
    }

private:
    QString m_name;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Test)
```

Now you can Imagine the same class, let's say, Check, but with Test property instead of QString. And I want just write

```
QJsonObject json;
json = Check(...);
```

It works with standard types, but I don't know what to do with my owns.

Perfectly, I want to use such "operator QJsonObject" to serialize any types in QObject. For example, inherit QList, implement those operators and use as any other objects for serializing

Comment: That link will be dead eventually. If there is more [mcve] that you need to provide, you should put it in the body of the question.

Comment: I'll try. Too many macro have been used

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/Skycoder42/QtJsonSerializer - a library created for exactly that purpose

Comment: no, it's created for serializing by hands. I want to use qt meta property system to avoid using implicit convertions. I want just write QJsonObject(MyClass()) without implementing enything

Comment: *explicit convertions

Comment: Thats just a question of how to use it. You could for example implement the operator to internally use the serializer. The reason I meantioned the library, is because it internally solved the problem you are currently experiencing using virtual converter classes. If you don't want to use it, you can see that as an example on how to handle this specific problem.

Comment: Question is not how to deserialize or serialize from/to json, but how to call deserialization method of QVariant. You can get Q_PROPERTY-defined property using metaObject->property(index), which returns QVariant. Then I need to call some method (any at all, my operators are just attempts to make it work) which transforms your Q_PROPERTY-defined property to QJsonObject. In other words, you don't know what is in QVariant - standard Qt type or your own type. And I need to transform them all into, for example, QJsonObject/Value without knowing what type is it